# Conversion of decimal hours to hours:minutes:seconds

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to convert a number of decimal hours (example: 4.96) and have it read 4:57:36 (4hrs, 57min, 36sec) in an Excel 2003 spreadsheet. I have this formula already, but it doesn't show the seconds. It returns a result of 4:58.

Here's the formula:

```
=TRUNC(A1)&":"&REPT("0",2-LEN(ROUND(60*(A1-TRUNC(A1)),0)))&ROUND(60*(A1-TRUNC(A1)),0)
```

What do I need to change to show the seconds too?

Answer (score 7):

Can't you just divide by 24 and custom format the result cell as [h]:mm:ss?

`=A1/24`

[image]

Comment: Yep, time values in Excel are stored internally as days and fractions of a day.

Comment: That's useful, but the reader should note that this a time value in a specific date. Not an absolute time value.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
=(INT(A1)/1440+MOD(A1,1)/1440)*60
```

[image]

Edit: if you insist on a text output (with all the negative implications that brings), just wrap the formula in a Text() function.

```
=TEXT((INT(A1)/1440+MOD(A1,1)/1440)*60,"hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I think your solution is a lot cleaner than mine (that just built upon the TRUNC H:M example) but it does need the cell to be formatted as datetime, otherwise it shows a decimal.

Comment: If the data type is date/time, it should be stored as a number and formatted accordingly. Storing date/time as text that looks like date/time only makes matters more complicated, for example if you want to run calculations on the values (difference between two times, etc). The extra click for applying a cell format other than text is well worth it in the long run. I've added a text version above, though.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works great   =(INT(A1)/1440+MOD(A1,1)/1440)*60  All I do is format the cell to display hh:mm:ss.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @teylyn I absolutely agree fields /should/ be formatted correctly. And your solution (date/time or text) is much cleaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your H:M is working correctly easiest way is to convert hour decimal to seconds and use MOD to check difference with division by 60.

So the formula would be:

```
=TRUNC(A1)&":"&REPT("0",2-LEN(ROUND(60*(A1-TRUNC(A1)),0)))&ROUND(60*(A1-TRUNC(A1)),0)&":"&REPT("0",2-LEN(ROUND(MOD(A1*60*60,60),0)))&ROUND(MOD(A1*60*60,60),0)
```

Comment: I don't think this works, Dave - for the example given the formula returns 4:58:36, i.e. one minute too high - it does that whenever the seconds part is > 30 - you can do this much more simply - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below formula,

if you want to convert the decimal number (A2) 10.58

`=TEXT(A2/24,"hh:mm:ss")`

the answer will be 10:34:48